# Access SQL Subtract Dates excluding weekends

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am able to run the query and update the days from the date it was created. However I would like to exclude weekend days, just Monday thru Friday.

Example:

```
UPDATE [Table1] SET [Table1].Days = DATE() - [Table1].DateCreated WHERE [Table1].Password = True AND [Table1].Complete = FALSE;
```

This will update the days to the value from the created date to current date, which would be 1,2,3, etc. However I need this to exclude the weekends. I don't run queries very often but I would like create this query.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: So, just 5 out of every 7 days?

Comment: Yes, Monday thru Friday. I only need business days of operation. I don't care about holidays, just the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you will be running your query from within an Access session, you can use a VBA user-defined function to compute the number of weekdays between two dates.

For example, consider the `WorkingDays()` function from the Access Web: [Calculate Number of Working Days](http://access.mvps.org/access/datetime/date0006.htm).  If I understand your query correctly, I think this may do what you want:

```
UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Table1].Days = WorkingDays([Table1].DateCreated, DATE())
WHERE [Table1].Password = True AND [Table1].Complete = FALSE;
```

On that same page, you can find a `WorkingDays2()` function which would allow you exclude holidays from the workdays count if that's useful.  You would need to set up a table for your holidays though.

If you will be doing this from outside an Access session, like from classic ASP or Dot.Net, you won't be able to use a user-defined function in the query.